# IBM Cloud / Can't see activity tracker events in logdna

Tags: ibm-cloud, logdna

we currently use IBM Cloud and the "depreciated" activity tracker in dallas. now we want to get some expierience with new "activity tracker with logdna". we installed one new instance in dallas and set the retention for our data to 14 days.
but after one day there is still no data in logdna. in the "old" activity tracker, we can see the logs.
can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the depreciated activity tracker all iam events where only collected in dallas. in the new activity tracker with logdna, our events are collected in eu-de.
now I created an instance in eu-de and we can see all events there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled your environments to send log events to the AT with LogDNA? Here is a [list of services and scenarios which can send those tracking events](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Log-Analysis-with-LogDNA?topic=LogDNA-cloud_services).

If you have Kubernetes clusters or Cloud Foundry, you would need to enable it. Check the [IBM Cloud Observability portal](https://cloud.ibm.com/observe), click on **Logging** and enable the instance.

There is a [guide on how to transition from the Cloud Activity Tracker to Activity Tracker with LogDNA](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/cloud-activity-tracker?topic=cloud-activity-tracker-transition).

Comment: thanks! we use activity tracker to monitor iam and changes to services. currently we do not use one of the services listed on this page. how can we display logins and iam changes in activity tracker with logdna?

Comment: You should see IAM events. I added a link to the transition guide which has info on how to set up roles and permissions.

Comment: that is what we did. my user has all permissions on this activity tracker with logdna instance. (Administrator, Manager, Editor, Operator, Anzeigeberechtigter, Leseberechtigter). we still can't see the iam events.

Comment: now i deleted the "at with logdna" and recreated it as account owner. result is the same - no events

Comment: If you followed the [transition] docs and don't see any events, I would recommend to open a support case